# Pass variables to build.xml from VSTS build

Tags: ant, azure-devops, salesforce, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up the build pipeline in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services), and I'm not able to pass a variable to the build. I don't know what the syntax should I use actually to get the variable in the build I guess. I created the variable in the VSTS:[image: VSTS variables]
I use standard build.xml file:

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="deployCodeAndRunTests" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

<property file="build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>

<!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
     so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
     will be treated literally.
-->
<condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="ant-salesforce.jar" />           
    </classpath>
</taskdef>          

<!-- Deploy code and run tests.  If test fails, rollback deploy. -->
<target name="deployCodeAndRunTests">
  <sf:deploy
        username="${sf.username}"
        password="${sf.password}"
        sessionId="${sf.sessionId}"
        serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
        maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}"
        deployRoot="..\src"
        testLevel="NoTestRun"
        rollbackOnError="true"
        logType="Detail"/>
</target>
```

Any suggestion on how to get the variables to the build?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? It's explained there.

Comment: you may check [these](https://www.google.com/search?ei=GpyFW4eIEozlkgXakahA&q=ant+pass+arguments+to+build.xml&oq=ant+pass+ar&gs_l=psy-ab.3.3.0i19k1l4j0i22i30i19k1l6.62834.64452.0.66822.7.7.0.0.0.0.124.822.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.818...0j0i67k1j0i10k1j0i22i30k1.0.PVXkApDpIsk)

Comment: I did check the documentation, but I didn't find the answer. Probably I don't know what exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: `<condition><not><isset>` is almost always pointless in Ant since properties are immutable. Just set your defaults with the `property` task. Command line properties are passed as `-Dkey=value`.

Comment: Hi @mascot, do you know how to pass the values to the build.properties file? Even though I'm able to pass the variable value to the script, it still searches for the values within the build.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the ant build with the parametrs from VSTS you need set them with the `property` task in build.xml

```
<property name="sf.username" value="${sfUsername}"/>
<property name="sf.password" value="${sfPassword}"/>
<property name="sf.serverurl" value="${sfServerurl}"/>    
<property name="sf.testLevel" value="${sfTestLevel}"/>
```

Then, when setting up the build in VSTS, you set it to run with parameters, where you assign the variables defined in VSTS. To run the ant build with parameters you use the `Options`:
[image: VST Ant build job]

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark your own reply as an answer.

Comment: Hi @mascot , do you know how to reference these variables in the "build.properties" file?

# Specify the login credentials for the desired Salesforce organization
sf.username = 
sf.password = 
sf.serverurl = 
sf.maxPoll = 2000